# Convert ItemId (EwsId) into EntryId in office addin

Tags: javascript, api, exchangewebservices, office-addins

I have an office addin (js), and I need this `EntryId` property to identify mails (I use this `EntryId` in a VSTO plugin, need it for BC)

After searching I have tried [ConvertId operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/convertid-operation) but I always get a `This request is invaild` response.

It turns out, `ConvertId` is not supported when using [makeEwsRequestAsync call](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services#ews-operations-that-add-ins-support).

So I thought about getting messages headers using `GetItem` but the PR_ENTRYID header is not returned:

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <soap:Header>
                <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                <GetItemInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                    <ItemShape>
                        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
                    </ItemShape>
                    <ItemIds><t:ItemId Id="${itemId}"/></ItemIds>
                </GetItemInfo>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

**tl;dr:** So what is the way to convert `EwsId` to `EntryId` in Office Addin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, ended up using `GetItem` operation with `ExtendedFieldURI`:

```js
    import xpath from 'xpath';
    import { DOMParser } from 'xmldom';
    import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

    private getEntryIdFromItemId(itemId: string): Promise<string>
    {
        const request = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <soap:Header>
                <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                <GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
                    <ItemShape>
                        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
                        <t:AdditionalProperties>
                          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x0FFF" PropertyType="Binary" />
                        </t:AdditionalProperties>
                    </ItemShape>
                    <ItemIds><t:ItemId Id="${itemId}"/></ItemIds>
                </GetItem>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>`;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, async (asyncResult) => {
                if(asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed)
                {
                    reject();
                    return;
                }

                const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(asyncResult.value);
                const entryId = xpath.select("//*[local-name()='Value']", doc)[0] as Node;
                const entryIdHex = new Buffer(entryId.textContent!, "base64").toString("hex").toUpperCase();
                resolve(entryIdHex);
            });
        });
    }
```

Also had to convert the returned base64 value to an hex value, since thats what Outlook client uses.

If you wonder how I figured the 0x0FFF value part, here is [how](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagentryid-canonical-property).

Comment: You can see all MAPI properties in MFCMAPI (https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi/releases/tag/20.0.20307.01) or OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy)

Comment: Thank you for this, will probably help in the future !